# How to reset navigation stack state in nested navigator in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

My code is similar to following. suppose currently my navigation stack history is:

Screen A> Screen B> Screen D.

From screen D on a button press I want to reset my navigation stack state/history like the follwing: Screen A> Screen F

But I am getting this error:

```
  The action 'RESET' with payload {"index":1,"routes":[{"name":"Screen A"},{"name":"Screen F"}]} was not handled by any navigator.
```

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen E" component={ScreenE} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen F" component={ScreenF} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen G" component={ScreenG} />
</Stack.Navigator>
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen A" component={ScreenA} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen B" component={ScreenB} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen C" component={ScreenC} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen D" component={ScreenC} />
</Tab.Navigator>

const ScreenD=({navigation})=>{ <Button title="reset stack" onPress={()=> navigation.reset({
        index: 1,
         routes: [{ name: "Screen A" }, { name: "Screen F" }],
       })} /> }
```

Comment: Did you saw this?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/navigation-actions/#reset

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar as i am using react navigation Version: 5.x, it gives the following error: "Unable to resolve "react-navigation" from "screens\ScreenD.jsx""

Comment: can you please add your package.json file too

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar  drive link of package.json https://drive.google.com/file/d/15I80o_RhM5t4jmiT49HW1SpUfwtrJmRt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are importing something from "react-navigation" in your "screens\ScreenD.jsx", you should use `@react-navigation/native` or `@react-navigation/stack` for importing.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions

this solved my problem....Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thank you, I was facing this issue too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CommonActions.reset() from here
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions

This Worked well.